# Adding an extra column with a value for each row in a data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView called `dataGridView1` that populates on form load. How do I add an extra column to the end with a date time stamp of "now" and make sure this `Created` column is on the end or the row?

I have tried:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Created","GETDATE()");
```

I populate the dataGridView1 like this:

```
private void DisplayAppropriateMessage(FacebookOAuthResult facebookOAuthResult)
{
    if (facebookOAuthResult != null)
    {
        if (facebookOAuthResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken);

            dynamic result = fb.Get("/me");
            var name = result.name;

            {

                var query = string.Format(@"SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name, friend_count, pic_big 
                        FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())");

                dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
                parameters.q = query;
                dynamic results = fb.Get("/fql", parameters);

                List<MyFriends> q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyFriends>>(results.data.ToString());

                dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
       }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(facebookOAuthResult.ErrorDescription);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will update my question...

Comment: looks like the question title and question content don't match each other, btw I don't really understand your question at all.

Comment: @KingKing : edits made.

Comment: How do you populate the grid?

Comment: using `Add` will append the column to the end for you, unless you want to ensure that all the next added column should locate before the fixed last column `Created`, you may have some other column added **dynamically** after the `Created` column has been added?

Comment: @Steve i think you've helped me with this before? Sorry

Comment: @KingKing any ideas how i can add the current date time to the end of each row in my grid view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<MyFriends> q` contains data returned by facebook.

You store it as `MyFriends` type (which BTW should be called `MyFriend` because each object stores data about one of your friends). Then you display this list of friends in `datagridview`. I don't know how you configured gridview but If I remember well it can create columns from displayed object's properties automatically or you can define them on your own.

So solution is to add property to `MyFriends` type with name `Created` and after you get results from Facebook just iterate over results and set their `Created` property to `DateTime.Now`. Depending on how you configured `datagridview` you will have to add column to it or not.